# Why vue cli 3 template or any other template has `h => h(App)` on main.js instead of just `new Vue(App)`?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

If you open any CodeSandbox Vue template or vue-cli 3 template, you can notice this code in `main.js`

#### Method 1

```js
new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

I'm a little bit confused about this code, why not just

#### Method 2

```js
new Vue(App).$mount("#app");
```

Is there any benefit of writing `Method 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a benefit - when you use the `options` object you can also add Vue-Router, Vuex, define some data, computed properties, watchers, methods and even some lifecycle hooks. For example:

```js
new Vue({
  data:
  {
    currentUser: null,
    lastError: null,
    showLoadingSpinner: false,
  },
  computed:
  {
    baseURL()
    {
      return process.env.BASE_URL;
    }
  },
  created()
  {
    this.$on('logout', this.logout);
  },
  beforeDestroy()
  {
    this.$off('logout', this.logout);
  },
  router: myRouter,
  store: myStore,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```